# Template Function: Using arrays for integers, doubles and chars. Add integers, multiply doubles, give ASCI value of chars

Tags: c++, sorting, templates

I've writen a template function **sort** to sort an array of any type (int, double, char) and I've put it into its own namespace "sort".

I now want to add another namespace "sort and calculate". I want this function to recognize whether the array is an integer, double or character. If it's a character, all numbers should be added together (sum), and if it's a double all numbers should be added together (product). I'm not sure how to write that if statement. Hope I've formulated my problem understandably. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace sorting {
template <typename T, typename G>
T sort(T array[], G size){
    std::cout << "Unsorted: ";
    for (int i = 0; i<size;i++)
        std::cout << array[i] << " ";
// Sort numbers
    T temp;
    for (int i=0; i<size;i++){
        for (int j=i+1; j<size; j++)
        {
            if (array[j] < array[i]){
                temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
//Sorted
    std::cout << std::endl << "Sortiert: ";
    for (int i=0; i<size;i++)
        std::cout << array[i] << " ";
    
    return 0;
}

}

namespace sort_and_calculate{
template <typename T, typename G>
T sort (T array[],G size, bool check = false){
    sorting::sort (array, size);
    
    if (check==true){
        
        T sum =0;
        for (int i=0; i<size;i++){
            sum += array[i];
        }
        std::cout << "Sum: " << sum << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

}

int main(){
    
    int int_array[] = {5,4,3,2,1};
    int size = 5;
    sort_and_calculate::sort(int_array, size, false);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you intend to have distinct behaviors of the function `sort_and_calculate::sort()` for different types then templates are the wrong choice maybe. In that case, you simply might write different overloads for `sort_and_calculate::sort()` for `int`, `double`, and `char`. They all still can share (i.e. call) the `sorting::sort()` function template.

Comment: I want to formulate an if statement to determine whether the given array is an integer, double or char and to act accordingly. For example, if it is an int array, I want all elements to be added to a sum (like in my code), but if its a double array, I want the elements to be multiplied instead.

Comment: Ohhhh, I see. Okay, probably overloading is the smarter choice here then. Thank you !

Comment: There is also the option to use an `if constexpr` somehow or template things with `std::enable_if`. That might help to share some code. However, I still struggle to believe that this makes the whole thing easier to read and understand. Finally, I would keep to put all reusable code into function templates and write multiple overloads for the rest which is individual for each type.